# Fetch comma seperated link list from MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

```
id      name
1       Abc
2       Bcd
3       Def
4       Efg
5       Xyz
```

Now i am using mysqli prepared statements to fetch my data

```
<?php
  if ($stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM TABLE")) {
      $stmt1->execute();
      $res1 = $stmt1->get_result();             
      while($rwv=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
?>

   <a href="page.php?name=<?php echo $rwv['name']; ?>"><?php echo $rwv['name']; ?></a>

<?php } } $stmt1->close(); ?>
```

Output i get on using above query:

```
AbcBcddefEfgXyz
```

Desired Ouput:

```
Abc, Bcd, Def, Efg, Xyz
```

I searched on Google and found solutions to use GROUP_CONCAT func. I used GROUP_CONCAT function but then it shows an error on a href that variable "name" is undefined. How i can get the desired output ?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just add the comma to the echo line in the while loop

Comment: Just add `echo " , "; ` after anchor tag

Comment: @JimL on adding a comma in echo, it will put a comma at last of the list also...I don't want a comma after Xyz...

Comment: Then don't add it if it's the last result.  Or add all the strings to an array and explode with ", ", or some other solution

Comment: @JimL How to know about last result...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is just terrible.

We are trying desperately to make PHP users to refrain from intermixing PHP with HTML, but that answer is lowering a problem a level deeper, intermixing HTML with SQL.

While using separation from HTML you can make your code real neat

```
<?php
    $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM users")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $last = count($data) - 1;
?>
<? foreach ($data as $i => $row) { ?>
    <a href="page.php?name=<?= $row['name'] ?>"><?= $row['name'] ?></a><!--
    --><?php if ($i != $last) { ?>,<?php } ?>
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check below example, You can use GROUP_CONCAT in mysql.

```
"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<','a href=\"pagename.php?name=', title, '\"\>', title, '<', '/a>')) as name FROM YOUR_TABLE"
```

The above example fetch the records with comma separated value from mysql with column name `name`, So you will not get the error as you mentioned above. May be it will help you.

Comment: I was sure still i confirmed that it generates complete comma separated list in href value...

Comment: Yes it will generate comma separated string in href, like `?name=ABC, Bcd, Def, Efg, Xyz`

Comment: Yeah i want to create a list like <a href=page.php?name=Abc>Abc</a>, <a href=page.php?name=Bcd>Bcd</a> and so on...

Comment: Ah, Now i get you. Please check my updated answer for that

Comment: Can you please edit little more as there are "" at starting and end of query. So in between "" are ending query in between..e.g.."SELECT..........FROM TABLE"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go that you can use with your existing code is: (added 3 lines to the code, all with comment //Added this

```
<?php
  if ($stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM TABLE")) {
      $stmt1->execute();
      $res1 = $stmt1->get_result();
      $hasGonePastFirst = false;  //Added this             
      while($rwv=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {

       if($hasGonePastFirst) echo ' , ';   //Added this
       else $hasGonePastFirst = true;      //Added this
?>

   <a href="page.php?name=<?php echo $rwv['name']; ?>"><?php echo $rwv['name']; ?></a>

<?php
 } } $stmt1->close(); ?>
```

Comment: it will put comma away from the value, which doesn't look nice

Comment: You mean after right? corrected the code, so it has the comma in the right place now, silly mistake. Or you mean the fact that I used " , " instead of ", "

Comment: it won't help if you even use  ", " because there is a lot of other space

Comment: Ahh definetly, I see what you mean now. From your solution, smart doing the comment inbetween